# Android 12 hours Time Format getting wrong

Tags: android, simpledateformat, date-format

I am using

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a");
String dateAsString = dateFormat.format(gmt);
```

And getting String 06-06-2017 08:15 a.m.
Why I am getting a.m. instated of AM or PM?

Comment: What is gmt??.as in the value in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AM/PM/a.m. actually depends on the device. Try the same code on other devices and you might get to see a different result. If you need AM/PM only, then you need to do it manually by replacing the dots and converting it to uppercase.

Comment: Welcome. Glad to help you.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the locale. If you use `SimpleDateFormat` (which you may not want to do, see below), I recommend you give it an explicit locale. The one you construct uses the device’s default, which explains why you get different results on different devices. If you want that, use `new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault())` so the reader knows you have thought about it. To make sure you get AM and PM, use for example `new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH)`.

Why would you not want to use `SimpleDateFormat`? I consider it long outdated since the much better replacement for the Java 1.0 and 1.1 classes came out with Java 8 in 2014. They have also been backported to Android Java 7 in the `ThreeTenABP`. Get this and write for example:

```
    LocalDateTime gmt = LocalDateTime.of(2017, Month.JUNE, 6, 8, 15);
    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-uuuu hh:mm a",
                                                                   Locale.ENGLISH);
    String dateAsString = gmt.format(dateTimeFormat);
```

The result is

```
06-06-2017 08:15 AM
```

To make explicit that the time is in GMT, you may use an `OffsetDateTime` with offset `ZoneOffset.UTC`.

Link: [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: The OP's issue is not only about the locale. Indeed, different Android devices and platforms use different localized data, even for the same `java.util.Locale`, so using Threeten-ABP would not defend against this behaviour.

Comment: Interesting, @MenoHochschild. I did not know that.

Comment: Oops, @MenoHochschild, just saw I forgot the locale in the modern code (contrary to my own advice a few lines earlier). Have fixed. Thanks for drawing my attention back to this answer. ThreeTenABP not defending makes sense: I guess (just a guess, though) that one of the points in ThreeTenABP over ThreeTen Backport is it uses the Android device’s settings like locale.

Comment: The only special point about ThreetenABP (versus the standard backport) is just: It is a thin wrapper around the backport and uses its own timezone provider for performance reasons (uses repackaging of the tz-data as assets). Localization is just delegated to the Android platform but no own i18n-data, no care about special Android settings like 12/24-hour-settings etc.